# SQL: Fazer comparação entre 2 colunas e retornar apenas 1

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tenho uma tabela de clientes que inclui clientes PF e PJ. Nessa Tabela, se o cliente tem CPF não tem CNPJ, se tem CNPJ não tem CPF.
Preciso de uma consulta que verifique quais das duas colunas não é nula e retorna somente ela. Tipo

```
SELECT nome, (cnpj or cpf) as documento FROM CLIENTES
where ...
```

Meu banco é Mysql, mas se tiver o código em outro BD relacional eu aceito, assim posso pesquisar sobre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `COALESCE`, quer retorna o primeiro valor de uma lista que não for nulo:

```
SELECT nome, COALESCE(cpf, cnpj) AS documento
```

Outra opção seria usando  `CASE WHEN` para resolver isso:

```
SELECT nome,
CASE 
    WHEN cpf IS NOT NULL
    THEN cpf
    ELSE cnpj
END
) AS documento
```

Documentação: [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) e [CASE WHEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo, isso mesmo.. Obrigado

Answer (score -2):

Você tem um problema de modelagem no seu banco. Um atributo multi valorado deveria originar uma terceira tabela (tabela própria), referenciada por chaves estrangeiras.
No caso, sua tabela clientes deveria estar ligada a outras duas, PF e PJ. É o clássico exemplo da entidade pessoa que deve ser especializadas em sua sub classes: pessoa física e pessoa jurídica.

Comment: Obrigado amigo pela resposta, mas possuo 2 tabelas(PF e PJ), mas a consulta é uma só. Eu quis simplificar a pergunta para que fique mais fácil e objetiva de ser respondida.